# What is the word for making a textual copy of a video tutorial?

Tags: vocabulary

My friend asked me to make a written/typed version of his video tutorial and more specifically I had to turn the narrator's voice into typed words and in some parts of the video need to capture a frame and add those images as figures/charts/... to the text so that the final result would be  a thing like an article, a booklet, a book or something printable on paper. I've searched for such a word but not found a solid case for it. I found few words--say verbs--such as compile, gather or collect, but I think it has to be a more appropriate word. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most commonly this is called a *transcript*, or sometimes a *transcription*, although the latter is also the name of the process of transcribing something.

If you publish anything that has been transcribed from the spoken word you can describe it as a transcript. If it is AI-generated then you may need to proofread and edit it, but the end result is still a transcript.

Comment: Just to clarify, the verb is "transcribe". The poster here uses that verb but doesn't explain it. The result of transcribing spoken or recorded words is a transcript, as he says. (I upvoted despite this quibble about clarity!)